# MongoError: Authentication failed with docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose, docker-compose

I am trying to build this app https://github.com/dwgebler/node-express-example. I want to use it as a template for making a Mongodb http express server. I tried to build the docker compose file in this repo which looks like this (modified slightly):

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  database:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo-database
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "mongodata:/data/db"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
  mongo-express:    
    image: mongo-express
    container_name: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongo-database
  web:
    image: node:16-alpine
    container_name: node-server
    restart: always
    user: "node"
    ports:
      - "9443:443"
    volumes:
      - "./app:/var/app/"
    working_dir: "/var/app"
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: dev
      DB_USER: root
      DB_PASSWORD: example
      DB_NAME: mongo-database
    command: "./wait.sh mongo-database 27017 'npm start'"
volumes:
  mongodata:
```

But when I run the command docker compose up -d in the same directory as the docker-compose.yml file, I get this in the "node-server" container logs:

```
Mongo started
MongoError: Authentication failed.
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (/var/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:272:20)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at processIncomingData (/var/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (/var/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:391:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:332:10)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:336:10)
    at Socket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:754:22)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 18,
  codeName: 'AuthenticationFailed'
}
```

Why am I getting a MongoError: Authentication failed? Notice that I set

```
DB_USER: root
DB_PASSWORD: example
DB_NAME: mongo-database
```

In the `web` section of the docker file which matches the `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME`, `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD`, from the database section and I set `DB_NAME` to `mongo-database` which matches the database section name. So why isn't it authenticating?

Comment: Try removing the volume in the Mongo container. The environment variables have 'INIT' in their names because they're only used when initializing a database. So if you already have a database in the volume you map, the variables aren't used.

Comment: I just tried removing the volume. Same error...

Comment: I tried, but I was unable to see the node-server logs in ./app

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` create a user in the Mongo admin database. Your connection string tries to authenticate against the `mongo-database` database and it can't find the user. There are messages in the Mongo logs that tell you this.

To fix it, you need to authenticate against the admin database by adding `authSource=admin` to your connection string, like this

```
const uri = `mongodb://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@mongo-database/${process.env.DB_NAME}?retryWrites=true&writeConcern=majority&authSource=admin`;
```